# compile php5 on centos with --enable-pcntl

Tags: compilation, centos

I am trying to enable pcntl on my php on centos. I see I am suppose to do a ./configure make build but have not ever done it. Could someone give me some direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want/need to compile PHP by yourself, you might want to take a look at [Apache 2.0 on Unix systems](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) : the process is not too complex, but it can take some time *(say between one and two hours)* if it's your firt time.

If you have more specific questions, don't hesitate to ask :-)

As you are using a distribution that provides RPM, though, one question comes to my mind : is there no RPM providing the pcntl extension, that you could use instead of re-compiling yourself ?

*(I don't have a CentOS machine to test, sorry)*

Comment: I did not think about looking for a rpm. I need these extensions.
    * PCNTL: --enable-pcntl
    * POSIX: --enable-posix
    * Sockets: --enable-sockets
    * SHMOP: --enable-shmop
    * SysVSem: --enable-sysvsem

Comment: I tried to find an PHP5 RPM but no luck. I ran ./configure and got this
<pre>
./configure
loading cache ./config.cache
checking for Cygwin environment... no
checking for mingw32 environment... no
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
configure: error: no acceptable cc found in $PATH
</pre>

Comment: Figured out cc or gcc was not installed.

Comment: This worked:
* Downloaded newest php5.3 by wget http://url at php.net
* I unzipped the file
* Went to folder php-5.3.0
* ran ./configure -enable-pcntl -enable-posix -enable-sockets -enable-shmop -enable-sysvsem
* Found gcc was not installed
* Installed gcc
* Ran config again
* Found libxml2 was not installed
* Rand config again
* PHP5.3.0 Complete
* make
* make test
* make install

Comment: kind of what I meant by "can take some time" : it's often about trial and error with the required libs ^^ Still, nice to know you succedeed !